# Pyramid: Is it possible to use Authorization without Authentication?

Tags: python, pyramid

My organization uses OpenAM SSO for authentication and my app is written in Pyramid. 
The user id will be passed in HTTP header. I can also configure it to pass groups and permissions as well which I can use in  **acl**. This makes the authentication in pyramid redundant. Is it possible to do away with Authenticaion Policy altogether and go with authorization alone?

Comment: Having the username passed in as a header is just a type of Athentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a way to tell pyramid's authorization system who the person is (their effective principals). That is the responsibility of the authentication policy, even if it's something as simple as parsing a header.

```
class CustomAuthenticationPolicy(object):
    def effective_principals(self, request):
        principals = [Everyone]

        identity = request.headers.get('x-identity')
        # validate the identity somehow
        if is_valid(identity):
            principals += [Authenticated, identity, 'g:editors']
        return principals

config.set_authentication_policy(CustomAuthenticationPolicy())
```

Comment: I used your solution and was able to solve the problem. Initially it complained that `CustomAuthenticationPolicy` has no attribute `unauthenticated_userid`. So I added that method to return a user id and it worked! Thank you @michael-merickel.

Comment: Yes, my solution was just for getting authorization to work. If you have any other code that calls `authenticated_userid` or `unauthenticated_userid` then you need to define the other methods.